# How to set queued alarm using pending intent ring at scheduled time even after restarted the device?

Tags: java, android, alarmmanager

I am trying to set alarm for each event in calendar through my app. Only if my device is ON, i could get scheduled alarm notifications. If i restart my device, once the alarm rings and all scheduled events after restart doesn't notify through alarm manager. Any help is highly appreciated and thanks in advance...

Answer (score 0):

add this in manifest

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED"/>
```

Comment: i did't find any mistakes in that, i think this not required here <category android:name="android.intent.category.HOME" /> i am not sure just check it what is the use..

Comment: if i restart the device, the alarm is ringing once. To stop that and have to ring alarm for each event at scheduled time.